# Bash readline command of scrolling terminal lines up/down

Tags: bash, key-binding, readline

What is the Bash readline command, ie. the phrasal words command, of scrolling terminal lines up/down with shift - Page up/down

How to have all complete Bash readline commands (that are used by putting in ~.inputrc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the Bash readline command, ie. the phrasal words command, of scrolling terminal lines up/down with shift - Page up/down

There isn't one. Terminal scrolling using Shift-PgUp/PgDn is handled by your terminal directly and is beyond what Readline would be able to control.

> How to have all complete Bash readline commands

They're listed in `man bash`.